# Sending Byte[] to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

I'd like to send a **large** **file** (by large I mean it's size exceed the the limit that WCF naturally allows) **to the server over a WCF service**. So as expected I can't because it does not let me unless I tweak the config file. Of course **I googled** and **I came across using the `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="3600" />`.**

But sadly, all the people who have suggested this, **have not explained where to add this tag** in the config file. **I included** that in there but it **caused an error** (web service didn't start, crashed right away).

So **where should it go** (if it solves the problem at all) in the config file? **In which tag/section should it be enclosed?**

Edit: 
I could figure how to properly use the tag and it doesn't raise any error now but, still not able to send **large** array: **(Array larger than about 25kb is not sent)**

This is how I included the tag:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="36000" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Are you sure you tried Google? Because http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: No, I don't see an example! I see a hierarchy! Right at the top.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: It crashes :D when I copy past it as explained in there. Exactly the same way.

Comment: Show us exactly what you copied and pasted, and tell us exactly what exception crashed it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Right within the `System.Web`, it underlines all the tag attributes.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add _an example_? **Show us**

Comment: What was the error? Why haven't you told us?

Comment: I checked, and I don't believe it. ***What was the error? Where did you place these tags?***

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? Typically these limits are setting on the WCF bindings.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: The error as I added in the question was solved, the problem now is that it does not work.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Sorry for wasting your time, simply stop commenting on this question if you feel like your time is being wasted! I didn't ask you to answer my question!

Comment: "Does not work". Could you give us _an example_ of how it does not work? Is there an exception?

Comment: I'll stop, but consider: I may not be the only reader who feels this way, but rather may be the only reader who _tells you_ that he feels this way. Clean up your questions so that I don't react this way, and you'll get much better answers.

Comment: "Array larger than about 25kb is not sent" what happens when you try to send an array larger than 25kb. _What is the error???_

Comment: @JLRishe: What happens is nothing happens :) anyway I figured it out

Answer (score -1):

I figured the problem, the `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2048000" executionTimeout="3600" />` has got nothing to do with sending large arrays over WCF. Of course the problem is still related to the config file and it can be solved by using the below config:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: I suggest having a gander at this some time: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It might explain why people were "nagging" you so much. Of course none of us knew the cause of the problem. You barely gave us any information, so how could we?

Comment: @JLRishe: The cause of the problem was invalid approach, like opening a can with a hammer. An expert can figure that out by looking at the title and the approach. Now I know this, if anyone posts a question about this I can "blindly answer" their questions. This website is not a technical support for WCF, but 'further information' is an old cliche that doesn't work all the time. IQ is what matters!

Comment: I think you'll see that nobody "blindly answer"ed your question. Yours is the only answer posted here.